# Regex to parse youtube link

Tags: regex, vb.net, url, youtube

While getting URL from youtube, those links are as follows:

- http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oSyL8WMLSB8
- http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4ioaMXTsAv8
- http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZYMR6Ex9REY
- http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ok_VQ8I7g6I

I need to parse it into as follows using regex in Vb.net

- http://www.youtube.com/v/oSyL8WMLSB8
- http://www.youtube.com/v/4ioaMXTsAv8
- http://www.youtube.com/v/ZYMR6Ex9REY
- http://www.youtube.com/v/ok_VQ8I7g6I

That means remove **`watch?`** and replace **`=`** with **`/`** after **`v`**.

Sorry I'm new to regex...

Comment: Why use a regex at all? It's overkill for this use case!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the below regex,

```
^(http:\/\/(?:www\.)?(?:youtube)\.com\/)[^?]+\?(v)=(.*)$
```

And in the replacement part, put the below

```
$1$2/$3
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/zN2vG6/4)

**OR**

You could use a lookbehind to match the characters which are just after to `.com/` upto the first `=` symbol.

```
(?<=\.com\/).*?=
```

And in the replacement part, replace the matched characters with,

```
v/
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/zN2vG6/5)

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
/watch\?v=/
```

with

```
"v/"
```

Example:

[image: img]
<sub>(source: [gyazo.com](http://gyazo.com/dea11fd83f7282048ffcc5c41b7af5bb.png))</sub>

[View a live regex demo!](https://regex101.com/r/sT7lN3/1)

---

**Edit:**

> That means remove watch? and replace = with / after v.

On that case, see the following regex replacement:

```
/watch?(v)=/
```

Replaces to:

```
"$1/"
```

Example:

[image: img]
<sub>(source: [gyazo.com](http://gyazo.com/fc4f3bdb397d5c01920b8c917786eda8.png))</sub>

[View a live regex demo!](https://regex101.com/r/sT7lN3/2)

Answer (score 1):

Regex is overkill for this, and you don't need to use one. A simple string replacement is entirely sufficient. In C# that looks like this:

```cs
string url1 = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oSyL8WMLSB8";
string url2 = url1.Replace("/watch?v=", "/v/");
// url2 => "http://www.youtube.com/v/oSyL8WMLSB8"
```

and in vb.net it looks like this:

```vb
Dim url1 As String = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oSyL8WMLSB8"
Dim url2 As String = url1.Replace("/watch?v=", "/v/")
' url2 => "http://www.youtube.com/v/oSyL8WMLSB8"
```